# Let T be a one-to-one linear transformation from $R^m$ to $R^n$ and B={$e_1$,$e_2$,...,$e_m$} a basis for $R^m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Prove that the set {T($e_1$),T($e_2$),...,T($e_m$)} is an independent set.

Let T : $R^n$ → $R^m$ be a linear transformation. Then there exists a unique matrix A
such that
T(x) = Ax
for all x in $R^n$
. We call A the standard matrix for the linear transformation T.

Comment: $\sum c_i T(e_i) = T \sum c_i e_i$. Now, can you show that $T$ is one-one if and only if $T(x) \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sum \alpha_k T(e_k) = 0$. Since $T$ is linear this gives
$T(\sum \alpha_k e_k) = 0$ and since $T$ is injective we have $\sum \alpha_k e_k = 0$. Since the $e_k$ form a basis, we have $\alpha_k =0$. Hence the
$T(e_k)$ are linearly independent.